# Linux user in group can't cd into directory with executable permission

Tags: linux, ubuntu

ok, someone suggested I try SuperUser. Here goes... I have user 'frances' that is a member of group 'pc', but cannot cd into a directory called pc, owned by pc and with executable permissions for group pc - 'permission denied'.

This should be amazingly simple. Can someone point out exactly what this idiot (me) is doing wrong? Here's a quick run-through, trying access as both 'pc' and 'frances':

```
pc@Samsung:/media$ ll             // check dir with user 'pc'
    total 12
    drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun  4  2014 ./
    drwxr-xr-x  23 root root 4096 Nov 27 06:55 ../
    drwxr-xr-x+  4 pc   pc   4096 Dec 10 19:09 pc/
pc@Samsung:/media$ cd pc           //success
pc@Samsung:/media/pc$ su - frances // change user
    Password: 
frances@Samsung:~$ cd /media
frances@Samsung:/media$ ls -la     // check dir with user 'frances'
    total 12
    drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun  4  2014 .
    drwxr-xr-x  23 root root 4096 Nov 27 06:55 ..
    drwxr-xr-x+  4 pc   pc   4096 Dec 10 19:09 pc
frances@Samsung:/media$ cd pc       //fail
    -su: cd: pc: Permission denied
frances@Samsung:/media$ groups frances  // groups 'frances is a member of includes 'pc'
    frances : pc cdrom plugdev users sambashare
```

Ubuntu 14.04...

Output of getfacl pc

```
frances@Samsung:/media$ getfacl pc
    # file: pc
    # owner: pc
    # group: pc
    user::rwx
    user:pc:r-x
    group::---
    mask::r-x
    other::r-x
```

Relevant lines of mount:

```
/dev/sda3 on /media/pc/data type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda1 on /media/pc/windows type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

Comment: I assume `/media/pc` is a mounted filesystem?  How was this filesystem mounted?  Did you happen to mount it with fuse perhaps?  Fuse has a feature to make a filesystem only useable by a single user.  http://serverfault.com/questions/188894/denied-root-access-to-user-mounted-fuse-file-system/188896#188896

Comment: Zoredache - that's a good lead - I'm heading into work now, will check in an hour or so!

Comment: Zoredache - can't remember how I mounted this but I just checked FUSE and this doesn't seem familiar. I've amended the question to include the output of 'mount'...

Comment: It is fuse based see the `type fuseblk` in your mount output.  But you have the `allow_other` option enabled, so you should be able to ignore that as the source of the problem.

Comment: Aha! But the 'fuesblk' bit only refers to a directory within 'pc' ie 'windows'? Should I still be able to navigate into 'pc'?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, helped via https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/42924/yoonix. The '+' indicates an acl is set. Add the user as follows:

setfacl -m u:frances:rx pc

solved.